# Android Textvew : Show 2nd date string in second line if width not available else show it in single line

Tags: android

[image]

show textview 2nd date string as whole if width is available .else move the 2nd date string as whole to next line .

Answer (score 0):

TextView support [getLineCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineCount%28%29)

> Return the number of lines of text, or 0 if the internal Layout has not been built.

After you have the line of TextView you should set text for TextView again

```
textView.setText("30 sep 2015 20 sep 2014"); // default text
int lines = textView.getLineCount();
if(lines == 2){
   textView.setText("30 sep 2015 \n 20 sep 2014"); // add \n for break line;
}else{
   // do nothing
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the answer .getLineCount =0 getLineCount() will give you the correct number of lines only after a layout pass.
It means that you need to render the TextView first before invoking the getLineCount() method.

Comment: of coure, you need to render the TextView first then count the line then set the text again. I explain very clearly in my code. I think it is the simple way to solve your problem. If you do not render textview first, how can you now textview have 1 or 2 line ???
Please check it again.
And if you think it is the correct answer you should mark it as correct answer. Thank you

Comment: You can use Phan's Answer with invisible TextView and then applied edited string into visible textView.